# C++ std::copy error: request for member ‘end’ in ‘__cont’, which is of non-class type ‘int* const’

Tags: c++

I have defined a struct in one class. There is a variable inside that struct:

```
struct Data
{
 int mAProfiles[Length];
}
```

In the class, I have a set method:

```
void setMAProfiles(int val[])
    {
        std::copy(std::begin(val), std::end(val), std::begin(Data.mAProfiles));
    }
```

but in the std::copy call, compile error happens as the following:

```
required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/range_access.h:78:5: error: request for member ‘end’ in ‘__cont’, which is of non-class type ‘int* const’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/range_access.h:97:5: note: template<class _Tp, long unsigned int _Nm> _Tp* std::end(_Tp (&)[_Nm])
     end(_Tp (&__arr)[_Nm])
```

what does that mean? I know I can use memcpy, but I want to know how to use that std::copy correctly.

**EDIT:**

I am using C++11, many of you said:

**On C++11 prefer**

**std::copy(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(b));**

Comment: The compiler is basically complaining that it does not know how big `val` is. How could you find the end of `val` in this function without using `std::end`?

Comment: Instead of raw arrays, simply always use `std::vector` or `std::array` (the latter only if the length is known at compile-time) and you wont have any problems like this.